# How can I get access to object of `QQmlApplicationEngine` inside a `QQuickItem` derived class?

Tags: c++, qt, qquickitem, qqmlapplicationengine

The variable `engine` in the following typical `main` function of a `QtApp` is a valid instance of `QQmlApplicationEngine`.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

  QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
  engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/qml/main.qml")));

  return app.exec();
}
```

**Is it possible to get access to object of `QQmlApplicationEngine` inside a function of a `QQuickItem` derived class? If yes, how?**

```
class TestItem : public QQuickItem {
public:
  TestItem();
  SomeMethod() {
     // Is it possible to get access to QQmlApplicationEngine here somehow ?
  }
}
```

Note that `TestItem` is registered on the `qml` side & displayed on the main window. I know that I can pass the `QQmlApplicationEngine` from `main` method. But, I have a hunch that because my `TestItem` is part of the window & holds the context. There should be a way to get an object or pointer to `QQmlApplicationEngine` without having to pass from `main` method ?

**The objective:** Using `QQmlApplicationEngine` I can get access to `QQuickItem`s in my `main.qml` by doing so:

```
QQuickItem *some_quick_item = qml_engine->rootObjects()[0]->findChild<QQuickItem*>("SomeQuickItem");
```

So for doing this, I want to the `QQmlApplicationEngine`. If theres a way to get access to other `QQuickItem`s from inside of one then please suggest.

Comment: If you are frequently going to access this object, I don't recommend searching for it each and every time. Find it once and store it where it will be quickly accessible.

Comment: yeah. agree. I passed in the qmlapplicationengine from main into the classes I need it in. so that works much better & there is one object of qmlapplicationengine throughout the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this static function:

```
QQmlEngine::contextForObject(this)->engine();
```

Of course, it might be a good idea whether `contextForObject()` returns a valid pointer before you try and invoke `engine()` for it.

Then you can use `qobject_cast<QQmlApplicationEngine*>(engine)` which should give you the desired pointer as long as your application is indeed a `QQmlApplicationEngine` based one.

Comment: this is returning `QQmlEngine`. what I need is `QQmlApplicationEngine`. Is there some way I cast or extract the `QQmlApplicationEngine` that I need ?

Comment: thanks for the answer. @dtech . is it possible for you to suggest something on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45693175/how-can-i-do-map-glframebufferobject-texture-to-a-qquickitem) question I raised yesterday ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45693175/how-can-i-do-map-glframebufferobject-texture-to-a-qquickitem