# How to set a QML instantiated item as a QImageProvider

Tags: c++, qt, qqmlengine

I have a class that inherits `QQuickItem` and `QQuickImageProvider`. This class is instantiated from qml. I need to call `QQmlEngine::addImageProvider` so that this class can actually provide images. I should be able to get the engine that my object exists in [as described in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45700420/3524982). In the constructor of my class I'm calling

```
QQmlEngine *engine = nullptr;
QQmlContext *context = QQmlEngine::contextForObject(this);
if (context)
    engine = context->engine();
if (engine)
    engine->addImageProvider("MyImageProvider", this);
```

But `QQmlEngine::contextForObject(this);` always returns a null pointer. Why does this not work?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Calling `QQmlEngine::contextForObject(this);` in the constructor doesn't work, I'm guessing because the object isn't done being constructed yet. If I make a `Q_INVOKABLE` function to register it later

```
void MyImageProvider::registerImageProvider()
{
    QQmlEngine *engine = nullptr;
    QQmlContext *context = QQmlEngine::contextForObject(this);
    if (context)
        engine = context->engine();
    if (engine) {
        engine->removeImageProvider("MyImageProvider");
        engine->addImageProvider("MyImageProvider", this);
    }
}
```

and then in my QML:

```
ImageProvider {
    id: myClass

    Component.onCompleted: myClass.registerImageProvider();
}
```

Then that works like a charm.

Comment: Or classBegin method